# Is there a way to hide value from input with password in React?

Tags: reactjs, passwords, controlled-component

I have this code for input with type="password"

```
<input
  type="password"
  id="password"
  value={form.password}
  onChange={handlePasswordChange}
/>
```

It works, but I noticed, that in develeopers console "Elements"you can actually see value of password field:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control undefined" value="qwerty">
```

Is it ok, that it shows password like this? Is there a way to hide it? Should i use uncontrolled componenets instead of controlled?

Comment: As long as you're not setting the value to an actual password, all the user would be able to see is the value they've entered.

Comment: That's good question.
Even in the Google SignUp we can see that.
Since you use this feature whenever user fills up the form him/her-self this is not a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`type="password"` only cosmetically hides the password. The input value is always accessible via JS (using it's `.value` property). So when someone opens DevTools, he or she will be able to get the password regardless.